# Get Worksheet index from title or instance using Openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, openpyxl, worksheet

How can someone get the Worksheet's index number using a Worksheet's property with Openpyxl?

The best example would be an Excel workbook that contains 3 sheets: "`Aaa`", "`Bbb`" and "`Ccc`". Knowing the title `"Bbb"`, what would be the way of getting the index number of that sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wb.worksheets.index(wb.get_sheet_by_name('Bbb'))` is the right answer. Thanks to BeeR for pointing it out.

Edit: With Openpyxl's update, the correct syntax would be

```
wb.worksheets.index(wb['Bbb'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this does not work for me.

For this code:

```
(...)
print(workbook.sheetnames)
print(workbook.worksheets.index('1.3'))
```

I get the following error:

> ['Übersicht', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.4', '1.5', '1.6', '1.7', '1.8',
>   '2.1', '2.2', '2.3', '2.4', '2.5', '2.6', '2.7', '2.8', '3.1']   File
>   ".../xlsx_tests.py", line 159, in 
>       print(workbook.worksheets.index('1.3')) ValueError: '1.3' is not in list

Comment: Hold on, this seems like a reasonnable comment of Charlie Clark's answer.

Comment: Confirmed. I have this issue. I accepted the original answer as I was in a hurry and the first answer poster seemed very confident. I will try to look into this error, since we have the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply and the suggestion to use `wb.get_sheet_by_name()`!
I can confirm that the following code works fine for me as well:

`source_sheet_name = '1.3'`

`ind_auto = workbook.worksheets.index(workbook.get_sheet_by_name(source_sheet_name))
 `

Comment: It's seems you should have written: workbook.sheetnames.index('1.3')